# Can't persist symfony collection with double embedded form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, persistence, formcollection

I receive the following error when trying to submit my form :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO UserIngredientSupplier (quantity, cost, createdAt, updatedAt, unitId,
>   organizationId, userIngredientId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with
>   params [1000, 4.5, "2014-11-27 22:46:51", "2014-11-27 22:46:51", 4, 2,
>   null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'userIngredientId' ne peut être vide (null)

I did not forget to put `'by_reference' => false`, I did not forget the `cascad={"persist"}` on my entities and I also put the setters for both my entities User and UserIngredients like :

My post parameters are the following :

```
[
  userIngredients => [
    0 => [
      nickname => Blé, 
      name => Ebly® - 500 g, 
      quantityInStock => 5000, 
      unit => 4, 
      userIngredientSuppliers => [
        0 => [
          quantity => 1000, 
          cost => 4.5, 
          unit => 4, 
          userSupplier => 2
        ]
      ]
    ], 
    1 => [
      nickname => Lait, 
      name => Lait Viva, 
      quantityInStock => 4000, 
      unit => 4
    ]
  ], 
  submit => , 
  _token => PRktvw2sSa7lBiZ9DIIAzhzaxg4ysWGyAazbZHPOnMA
]
```

What I am missing ? What would the `UserIngredientId` not be persisted ? Does it not come with the `UserIngredientSupplierType` being called from the `UserIngredientType` ?

Controller:

```
    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new FoodAnalyticsUserIngredient entity.
     *
     * @Route("/ing1", name="ing1")
     * @Method({"PUT","GET"})
     * @Template(":FoodAnalytics/UserIngredient:ing1.html.twig")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array|SymfonyComponentHttpFoundationRedirectResponse
     */
    public function parameterIng1Action(Request $request)
    {
        $userIngredientManager = $this->get('user_ingredient_manager');
        $ingredient = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:FoodAnalyticsUserIngredient')->findOneById(5);
        $parameterUserIngredientsForm = $userIngredientManager->getParameterIng1Form($ingredient);


        if ($request->getMethod()=='PUT')
        {
            $formManager = $this->get('form_manager');

            if ($formManager->handleRequestAndFlush($parameterUserIngredientsForm,$ingredient))
            {
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('my_ingredients').'/parameter_selection');
            }
        }

        return array(
            'parameter_user_ingredients_form' => $parameterUserIngredientsForm->createView()
        );
    }


    /**
     * @return SymfonyComponentFormForm|SymfonyComponentFormFormInterface
     */
    public function getParameterIng1Form($ingredient)
    {
        $unitRepository = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:FoodAnalyticsUnit');

        $userIngredientsForm = $this->formManager->createForm(
            new UserIngredientType($unitRepository),
            $ingredient,
            'PUT',
            'ing1',
            null,
            'Enregistrer les changements'
        );

        return $userIngredientsForm;
    }
```

Form type:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundleFormFoodAnalytics;

use AppBundleFormEventListenerAddUnitFieldSubscriber;
use AppBundleRepositoryFoodAnalyticsUnitRepository;
use SymfonyComponentFormAbstractType;
use SymfonyComponentFormFormBuilderInterface;
use SymfonyComponentOptionsResolverOptionsResolverInterface;

class UserIngredientType extends AbstractType
{

    protected $unitRepository;

    public function __construct(UnitRepository $unitRepository)
    {
        $this->unitRepository = $unitRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nickname', null, array(
                    'label'=>'Nom raccourci',
                    'attr'=>array(
                        'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                        'data-placement'=>"top",
                        'title'=>"Le nom raccourci peut être utilisé dans les recettes. Il doit être unique",
                        'class' => 'input-sm'
                    )))
            ->add('name', null, array(
                    'label'=>'Nom complet',
                    'attr'=>array(
                        'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                        'data-placement'=>"top",
                        'title'=>"Le nom complet peut être utilisé dans les recettes. Il doit être unique.",
                        'class' => 'input-sm'
                    )))
            ->add('quantityInStock', null, array(
                    'label'=>'Stock',
                    'attr'=>array(
                        'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                        'data-placement'=>"top",
                        'title'=>"Indiquez l'état de votre stock pour gérer vos commandes",
                        'class' => 'input-sm'
                    )))
            ->add('userIngredientSuppliers', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new UserIngredientSupplierType($this->unitRepository),
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                ))
        ;

        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddUnitFieldSubscriber($this->unitRepository));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserIngredient'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_foodanalytics_user_ingredient';
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundleEntityFoodAnalytics;
use AppBundleModelBaseCategoryClass;
use DoctrineCommonCollectionsArrayCollection;
use DoctrineORMMapping AS ORM;
use GedmoMappingAnnotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORMEntity(repositoryClass="AppBundleRepositoryFoodAnalyticsUserIngredientRepository")
 * @GedmoTree(type="nested")
 */
class UserIngredient extends BaseCategoryClass
{
    /**
     * @ORMId
     * @ORMColumn(type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORMGeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORMColumn(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $isImported;

    /**
     * @ORMColumn(type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORMColumn(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nickname;

    /**
     * @ORMColumn(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $quantityInStock;

    /**
     * @ORMManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundleEntityMarketPlaceProduct", inversedBy="userIngredients")
     * @ORMJoinColumn(name="productId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="cascade")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @GedmoBlameable(on="create")
     * @ORMManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundleEntityUserUser", inversedBy="userIngredients")
     * @ORMJoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="cascade")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORMManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUnit")
     * @ORMJoinColumn(name="unitId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="restrict")
     */
    private $unit;

    /**
     * @ORMOneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserRecipeIngredient", mappedBy="userIngredient")
     */
    protected $userRecipeIngredients;

    /**
     * @ORMOneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserIngredientSupplier", mappedBy="userIngredient", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $userIngredientSuppliers;

    /**
     * @GedmoTreeParent
     * @ORMManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserIngredient", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORMJoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $parent;

    /**
     * @ORMOneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserIngredient", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $children;


    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return UserIngredient
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set nickname
     *
     * @param string $nickname
     *
     * @return UserIngredient
     */
    public function setNickname($nickname)
    {
        $this->nickname = $nickname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nickname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNickname()
    {
        return $this->nickname;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantityInStock
     *
     * @param float $quantityInStock
     *
     * @return UserIngredient
     */
    public function setQuantityInStock($quantityInStock)
    {
        $this->quantityInStock = $quantityInStock;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantityInStock
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQuantityInStock()
    {
        return $this->quantityInStock;
    }

    /**
     * Set product
     *
     * @param AppBundleEntityMarketPlaceProduct $product
     *
     * @return UserIngredient
     */
    public function setProduct(AppBundleEntityMarketPlaceProduct $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return AppBundleEntityMarketPlaceProduct
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param AppBundleEntityUserUser $user
     *
     * @return UserIngredient
     */
    public function setUser(AppBundleEntityUserUser $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return AppBundleEntityUserUser
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set unit
     *
     * @param AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUnit $unit
     *
     * @return UserIngredient
     */
    public function setUnit(AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUnit $unit)
    {
        $this->unit = $unit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get unit
     *
     * @return AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUnit
     */
    public function getUnit()
    {
        return $this->unit;
    }

    /**
     * Set isImported
     *
     * @param boolean $isImported
     *
     * @return UserIngredient
     */
    public function setIsImported($isImported)
    {
        $this->isImported = $isImported;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isImported
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsImported()
    {
        return $this->isImported;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userRecipeIngredients = new DoctrineCommonCollectionsArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add userRecipeIngredient
     *
     * @param AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserRecipeIngredient $userRecipeIngredient
     *
     * @return UserIngredient
     */
    public function addUserRecipeIngredient(AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserRecipeIngredient $userRecipeIngredient)
    {
        $this->userRecipeIngredients[] = $userRecipeIngredient;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove userRecipeIngredient
     *
     * @param AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserRecipeIngredient $userRecipeIngredient
     */
    public function removeUserRecipeIngredient(AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserRecipeIngredient $userRecipeIngredient)
    {
        $this->userRecipeIngredients->removeElement($userRecipeIngredient);
    }

    /**
     * Get userRecipeIngredients
     *
     * @return DoctrineCommonCollectionsCollection
     */
    public function getUserRecipeIngredients()
    {
        return $this->userRecipeIngredients;
    }

    /**
     * Add userIngredientSupplier
     *
     * @param AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserIngredientSupplier $userIngredientSupplier
     *
     * @return UserIngredient
     */
    public function addUserIngredientSupplier(AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserIngredientSupplier $userIngredientSupplier)
    {
        //Needed cause the setter wouldn't be called even with by_reference = false
//        $userIngredientSupplier->setUserIngredient($this);

        $this->userIngredientSuppliers[] = $userIngredientSupplier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove userIngredientSupplier
     *
     * @param AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserIngredientSupplier $userIngredientSupplier
     */
    public function removeUserIngredientSupplier(AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserIngredientSupplier $userIngredientSupplier)
    {
        $this->userIngredientSuppliers->removeElement($userIngredientSupplier);
    }

    /**
     * Get userIngredientSuppliers
     *
     * @return DoctrineCommonCollectionsCollection
     */
    public function getUserIngredientSuppliers()
    {
        return $this->userIngredientSuppliers;
    }

    /**
     * Set userIngredientSuppliers
     *
     * @param ArrayCollection $userIngredientSuppliers
     * @return DoctrineCommonCollectionsCollection
     */
    public function setUserIngredientSuppliers(ArrayCollection $userIngredientSuppliers)
    {
        /** @var $userIngredientSupplier UserIngredientSupplier */
        foreach ($userIngredientSuppliers as $userIngredientSupplier)
        {
            $userIngredientSupplier->setUserIngredient($this);
        }

        exit(var_dump($userIngredientSuppliers));

        $this->userIngredientSuppliers=$userIngredientSuppliers;
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundleEntityFoodAnalytics;
use DoctrineORMMapping AS ORM;
use GedmoMappingAnnotation as Gedmo;
use GedmoTimestampableTraitsTimestampableEntity;

/**
 * @ORMEntity(repositoryClass="AppBundleRepositoryFoodAnalyticsUserIngredientSupplierRepository")
 */
class UserIngredientSupplier
{
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORMId
     * @ORMColumn(type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORMGeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORMColumn(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @ORMColumn(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cost;

    /**
     * @ORMManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUnit")
     * @ORMJoinColumn(name="unitId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="restrict")
     */
    private $unit;

    /**
     * @ORMManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserSupplier", inversedBy="userIngredientSuppliers")
     * @ORMJoinColumn(name="organizationId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="cascade")
     */
    private $userSupplier;

    /**
     * @ORMManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserIngredient", inversedBy="userIngredientSuppliers")
     * @ORMJoinColumn(name="userIngredientId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="cascade")
     */
    private $userIngredient;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantity
     *
     * @param string $quantity
     *
     * @return UserIngredientSupplier
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantity
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * Set cost
     *
     * @param string $cost
     *
     * @return UserIngredientSupplier
     */
    public function setCost($cost)
    {
        $this->cost = $cost;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cost
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCost()
    {
        return $this->cost;
    }

    /**
     * Set userSupplier
     *
     * @param AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserSupplier $userSupplier
     *
     * @return UserIngredientSupplier
     */
    public function setUserSupplier(AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserSupplier $userSupplier = null)
    {
        $this->userSupplier = $userSupplier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userSupplier
     *
     * @return AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserSupplier
     */
    public function getUserSupplier()
    {
        return $this->userSupplier;
    }

    /**
     * Set userIngredient
     *
     * @param AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserIngredient $userIngredient
     *
     * @return UserIngredientSupplier
     */
    public function setUserIngredient(AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserIngredient $userIngredient)
    {
        $this->userIngredient = $userIngredient;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userIngredient
     *
     * @return AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUserIngredient
     */
    public function getUserIngredient()
    {
        return $this->userIngredient;
    }

    /**
     * Set unit
     *
     * @param AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUnit $unit
     *
     * @return UserIngredientSupplier
     */
    public function setUnit(AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUnit $unit)
    {
        $this->unit = $unit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get unit
     *
     * @return AppBundleEntityFoodAnalyticsUnit
     */
    public function getUnit()
    {
        return $this->unit;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post code for the Entities, without the code cannot help you.

Comment: Hi, I have added complete source to be downloaded. If you think something special is of interest, don't hesitate to ask me, and thanks!

Comment: Those links wont work. Try visit them and you'll see that they only show PHP errors

Comment: sorry, for sure the code is executed. to read the code you need to download source. I don't have a live example yet, I can just provide the raw code. try right click, save target as...

Comment: you haven't uploaded the source. Can you please either post the code here or paste it into http://codebin.org/ and add links here. Thanks.

Comment: I have just added the full code at the end : the controller, the manager, the form, both entities. Problem is narrowed down to the relation between UserIngredient and UserIngredientSupplier, I've excluded the User. The EventSubscriber in the form is also not the source of error and related $builder->addEvent... can be removed, I had the error before and I am using it without any problem elsewhere.

Comment: in `addUserIngredientSupplier` you've set thing right, but why do you loop in `setUserIngredientSuppliers`, you should do the same as in `addUserIngredientSupplier`. Try change that and remove that `exit()` line and let me know what is going on.

Comment: thanks for taking the time. Actually I'm trying for this setUserIngredientSuppliers to be called as explained there http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html when using by_reference=>false in the form. The setter is not called like it should be, I never reach the exit. Removing a UserIgredientSupplier does not work. And adding one is only possible because of this extra line I've put in addUserIngredientSupplier.

Comment: well, removing has been fixed, I didn't put the appropriate code from the same link I quoted. But the setter not being called is still a mistery. does it only work when creating a new entity ?